# Correct page layout for a record type is only working in salesforce classic but not in lightning?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, page-layout, record-type

Hi can anyone help me out? I have a custom object and I created a new page layout and assigned this layout to the record type. However, different page layout is showing for the record type when I switch to Lightning page. In salesforce classic, everything is working fine. What might be the possible solution and cause of this?

Comment: Can you please add the screenshots?

Comment: Done uploading the image. I am under the same profile and same record type. When inserting a new record, different layout is showing up in classic and lightning

Comment: Can you edit to add what your Lightning Record Page configuration looks like? It's possible you have Dynamic Forms configured on the object, in which case the fields configured with that feature would be used in place of the Page Layout

Comment: Hi @JeffKranz, it works now. Thank you so much! I didn't know that there was such thing as Dynamic Form. Greatly Appreciated it!

Comment: Tempted to edit the main question.
This situation also affects the standard "New Record" pages too, not just the Lightning page layout.
e.g. New Opportunity Button, New Account Button, New Contact button are all affected by the App (Application in the waffle menu) you are currently on.

Answer (score 1):

If you have enabled dynamic forms on the object then it is overriding the page layout. Once you enable dynamic forms for a lightning record page, the New button for the object no longer uses the assigned page layout, it uses the dynamic fields from the lightning page.

I found the similar issue please have a look for more details :
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A97NUSAZ

Comment: Thank you for this answer.
This situation is not just for the lightning page but also for the New record pages. when dynamic forms is turned on.

IF ONLY Salesforce advised this in the PageLayout assignment section.